# Anyone know the cause of (rain) water leaks in '16 Nissan Pathfinder trunk storage area?

Tags: nissan, water-leak, pathfinder

Just bought a 2016 Nissan Pathfinder 2 weeks ago (a Friday). It poured rain the following Saturday night + all day Sunday + Monday.  By Monday afternoon the stench that filled the car was unbearable!! It smelled like a trash dump! Found small poool of water in back storage compartment. Smell went away 2 days later.  Then it rained really heavy again about 2 days after that, and the smell was back! This time we found a much larger pool of water in the same area (trunk/storage compartment). Took it back to the dealership, they couldn't find the source of the leak!   Anyone else heard of this?? [image][image]

Comment: Was car parked the entire time or was it driven during the rainstorm?

Answer (score 1):

Leaking seal, either window / tailgate or one of the side windows.
Or one of the rear light seals, good luck tracing it...

One method is to be in the car and have someone spraying water from a hose...